# How can I enable Worker in an existing Nextjs project?

Tags: next.js

I realised that I would like to make use of a Worker in my Nextjs project but since it's already created, how can I enable this?

At the time of creating the project I could have used `npx create-next-app --example with-web-worker` but how can I add this option once the project has been created?

Running the following command in my existing project isn't working

```
npx create-next-app . --with-web-worker
```

Output:

```
npx: installed 1 in 3.02s
The directory src contains files that could conflict:

  .env.local
  .eslintrc.json
  .next/
  .prettierignore
  .prettierrc.json
  Dockerfile
  README.md
  my-app/
  next.config.js
  node_modules/
  package-lock.json
  package.json
  pages/
  public/
  styles/
  with-web-worker/
  workers/

Either try using a new directory name, or remove the files listed above.
```

Trying to use create-next-app but in a different directory as suggested, below is what I experienced.

```
Success! Created with-web-worker-app at /src/test/with-web-worker-app
Inside that directory, you can run several commands:

  npm run dev
    Starts the development server.

  npm run build
    Builds the app for production.

  npm start
    Runs the built app in production mode.

We suggest that you begin by typing:

  cd with-web-worker-app
  npm run dev
```

Now running: `npm run dev`

```
> @ dev /src/test/with-web-worker-app
> next dev

ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
error - Failed to load next.config.js, see more info here https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-config-error
Error: Not supported
    at Object.loadConfig [as default] (/src/test/with-web-worker-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/config.js:399:74)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `next dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-10-28T11_40_34_433Z-debug.log
root@70c71730b6de:/src/test/with-web-worker-app# cat /root/.npm/_logs/2021-10-28T11_40_34_433Z-debug.log
```

So I copied the next.config.js file from the parent folder and reran `npm run dev`

Same output

```
> @ dev /src/test/with-web-worker-app
> next dev

ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
error - Failed to load next.config.js, see more info here https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-config-error
Error: Not supported
    at Object.loadConfig [as default] (/src/test/with-web-worker-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/config.js:399:74)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `next dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-10-28T11_43_50_236Z-debug.log
```

Update

I created /test outside the /src folder and ran `/test# npx create-next-app --example with-web-worker webworkerapp`

And I got

```
Success! Created webworkerapp at /test/webworkerapp
Inside that directory, you can run several commands:

  npm run dev
    Starts the development server.

  npm run build
    Builds the app for production.

  npm start
    Runs the built app in production mode.

We suggest that you begin by typing:

  cd webworkerapp
  npm run dev
```

Now `/test/webworkerapp# npm run dev`

Output:

```
> @ dev /test/webworkerapp
> next dev

ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
event - compiled successfully in 10.2s (159 modules)
Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
https://nextjs.org/telemetry

wait  - compiling /_error...
event - compiled successfully in 918 ms (160 modules)
Error [ERR_METHOD_NOT_IMPLEMENTED]: The _write() method is not implemented
    at Writable._write (_stream_writable.js:566:6)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:415:12)
    at clearBuffer (_stream_writable.js:545:7)
    at Writable.uncork (_stream_writable.js:319:7)
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:976:17
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:960:13
    at rhs (/test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:960:47)
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:978:9
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:960:13
    at Promise (/test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:991:9)
wait  - compiling /...
event - compiled successfully in 1867 ms (193 modules)
Error [ERR_METHOD_NOT_IMPLEMENTED]: The _write() method is not implemented
    at Writable._write (_stream_writable.js:566:6)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:415:12)
    at clearBuffer (_stream_writable.js:545:7)
    at Writable.uncork (_stream_writable.js:319:7)
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:976:17
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:960:13
    at rhs (/test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:960:47)
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:978:9
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:960:13
    at Promise (/test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:991:9)
error - Error [ERR_METHOD_NOT_IMPLEMENTED]: The _write() method is not implemented
Error [ERR_METHOD_NOT_IMPLEMENTED]: The _write() method is not implemented
    at Writable._write (_stream_writable.js:566:6)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:415:12)
    at clearBuffer (_stream_writable.js:545:7)
    at Writable.uncork (_stream_writable.js:319:7)
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:976:17
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:960:13
    at rhs (/test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:960:47)
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:978:9
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:960:13
    at Promise (/test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:991:9)
Error [ERR_METHOD_NOT_IMPLEMENTED]: The _write() method is not implemented
    at Writable._write (_stream_writable.js:566:6)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:415:12)
    at clearBuffer (_stream_writable.js:545:7)
    at Writable.uncork (_stream_writable.js:319:7)
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:976:17
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:960:13
    at rhs (/test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:960:47)
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:978:9
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:960:13
    at Promise (/test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:991:9)
error - Error [ERR_METHOD_NOT_IMPLEMENTED]: The _write() method is not implemented
Error [ERR_METHOD_NOT_IMPLEMENTED]: The _write() method is not implemented
    at Writable._write (_stream_writable.js:566:6)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:415:12)
    at clearBuffer (_stream_writable.js:545:7)
    at Writable.uncork (_stream_writable.js:319:7)
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:976:17
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:960:13
    at rhs (/test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:960:47)
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:978:9
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:960:13
    at Promise (/test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:991:9)
Error [ERR_METHOD_NOT_IMPLEMENTED]: The _write() method is not implemented
    at Writable._write (_stream_writable.js:566:6)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:415:12)
    at clearBuffer (_stream_writable.js:545:7)
    at Writable.uncork (_stream_writable.js:319:7)
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:976:17
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:960:13
    at rhs (/test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:960:47)
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:978:9
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:960:13
    at Promise (/test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:991:9)
Error [ERR_METHOD_NOT_IMPLEMENTED]: The _write() method is not implemented
    at Writable._write (_stream_writable.js:566:6)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:415:12)
    at clearBuffer (_stream_writable.js:545:7)
    at Writable.uncork (_stream_writable.js:319:7)
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:976:17
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:960:13
    at rhs (/test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:960:47)
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:978:9
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:960:13
    at Promise (/test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:991:9)
error - Error [ERR_METHOD_NOT_IMPLEMENTED]: The _write() method is not implemented
Error [ERR_METHOD_NOT_IMPLEMENTED]: The _write() method is not implemented
    at Writable._write (_stream_writable.js:566:6)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:415:12)
    at clearBuffer (_stream_writable.js:545:7)
    at Writable.uncork (_stream_writable.js:319:7)
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:976:17
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:960:13
    at rhs (/test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:960:47)
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:978:9
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:960:13
    at Promise (/test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:991:9)
Error [ERR_METHOD_NOT_IMPLEMENTED]: The _write() method is not implemented
    at Writable._write (_stream_writable.js:566:6)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:415:12)
    at clearBuffer (_stream_writable.js:545:7)
    at Writable.uncork (_stream_writable.js:319:7)
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:976:17
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:960:13
    at rhs (/test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:960:47)
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:978:9
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:960:13
    at Promise (/test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:991:9)
Error [ERR_METHOD_NOT_IMPLEMENTED]: The _write() method is not implemented
    at Writable._write (_stream_writable.js:566:6)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:415:12)
    at clearBuffer (_stream_writable.js:545:7)
    at Writable.uncork (_stream_writable.js:319:7)
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:976:17
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:960:13
    at rhs (/test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:960:47)
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:978:9
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:960:13
    at Promise (/test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:991:9)
error - Error [ERR_METHOD_NOT_IMPLEMENTED]: The _write() method is not implemented
Error [ERR_METHOD_NOT_IMPLEMENTED]: The _write() method is not implemented
    at Writable._write (_stream_writable.js:566:6)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:415:12)
    at clearBuffer (_stream_writable.js:545:7)
    at Writable.uncork (_stream_writable.js:319:7)
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:976:17
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:960:13
    at rhs (/test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:960:47)
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:978:9
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:960:13
    at Promise (/test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:991:9)
Error [ERR_METHOD_NOT_IMPLEMENTED]: The _write() method is not implemented
    at Writable._write (_stream_writable.js:566:6)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:415:12)
    at clearBuffer (_stream_writable.js:545:7)
    at Writable.uncork (_stream_writable.js:319:7)
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:976:17
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:960:13
    at rhs (/test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:960:47)
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:978:9
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:960:13
    at Promise (/test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:991:9)
Error [ERR_METHOD_NOT_IMPLEMENTED]: The _write() method is not implemented
    at Writable._write (_stream_writable.js:566:6)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:415:12)
    at clearBuffer (_stream_writable.js:545:7)
    at Writable.uncork (_stream_writable.js:319:7)
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:976:17
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:960:13
    at rhs (/test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:960:47)
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:978:9
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:960:13
    at Promise (/test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:991:9)
error - Error [ERR_METHOD_NOT_IMPLEMENTED]: The _write() method is not implemented
Error [ERR_METHOD_NOT_IMPLEMENTED]: The _write() method is not implemented
    at Writable._write (_stream_writable.js:566:6)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:415:12)
    at clearBuffer (_stream_writable.js:545:7)
    at Writable.uncork (_stream_writable.js:319:7)
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:976:17
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:960:13
    at rhs (/test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:960:47)
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:978:9
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:960:13
    at Promise (/test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:991:9)
Error [ERR_METHOD_NOT_IMPLEMENTED]: The _write() method is not implemented
    at Writable._write (_stream_writable.js:566:6)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:415:12)
    at clearBuffer (_stream_writable.js:545:7)
    at Writable.uncork (_stream_writable.js:319:7)
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:976:17
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:960:13
    at rhs (/test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:960:47)
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:978:9
    at /test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:960:13
    at Promise (/test/webworkerapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:991:9)
```

This could be a Docker problem.

Comment: `create-next-app` is meant to be used to quickly bootstrap new projects. Have you considered creating a separate project and copy the relevant files over?

Comment: Yeah I did, I updated the question with the result

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the issue. I've created a new project with `npx create-next-app --example with-web-worker` and was able to successfully run `npm run dev` from the root folder.

Comment: I'll give it another try, the error I had could be a docker thing